# AfterUpdate is fired before the modification in the access database

Tags: ms-access

On Ms Access 2003, I have some data bounded to a table with one *True/False* column named *Selection* I can check.

I need to update a Textbox with the count of selected item. (*Selection = True*)

When I use the *AfterUpdate* event of the checkbox, I noticed that the modification in the dabase wasn't effective so I have the wrong number of selected item (When I check one line, I have count - 1, when I uncheck, I have count + 1)

Do you know a workaround ?

I tryied that :

```
  nombreSelections = DCount("*", "TmpSelectionPalette", "Selection = True")
  If (Selection.value) Then
        nombreSelections = nombreSelections + 1
  Else
        nombreSelections = nombreSelections - 1
  End If
```

But that trick doesn't work, sometimes I have the good count, sometimes not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use `DCount()` and you want the count to update immediately after you click the checkbox you need to set the form's `.Dirty` property to `False` to commit (write) the change to the table. That is, you need something like this:

```
Private Sub chkSelection_AfterUpdate()
Me.Dirty = False  '' commit changes
Me.txtSelectedCount.Value = DCount("*", "Clients", "Selection")
End Sub
```